# Animation Nodes, Finding Points Inside an Object That is Inside an Object

Tags: animation-nodes

Below is an image showing nodes that I am using to find points inside a collection of objects and finding the material closest to those points. It works well however if there is an object inside an object(imagine an orange inside a soccer ball) There is no guarantee it will find the inside object. For example if the larger object is blue and the inside object is red the patch will assume all points are blue. It would be nice to generalize this so for example if there is a green object inside a red object inside a blue object, the patch would detect all points inside the green object to be green and points between the green surface and red surface to be red and points between the red surface and blue surface to be blue. Sorry I know this sounds complicated, just wondering where best to start.

[image: Nodes Finding Points In an Object]

Comment: I think it will be easier to find nearest point/index first. Then mask those are inside volume.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this setup,

Here nearest object is found first then it checks for inside volume condition.

[image]

[image]